# Integration between GWT and JasperReport

Tags: hibernate, web-applications, gwt, jasper-reports

Ho to integrate JasperReport and GWT? What is more, I use Hibernate in this poroject.

Comment: Can you provide some details on the integration of GWT 3.0 and Kasper Reports? Thank You

Comment: I benefited from the advice, that Samurai Soul gave me. Everything is on the server side in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have several applications that use JasperReport and GWT (and hibernate). However, all of the printing takes place on the server side. It's not possible with Jasper on the client. There is nothing special to code. Create a normal GWT app, and then produce your printed reports as you would in a normal web application. We generate a pdf and display it in a new browser tab/window.